# Github: fork a repo vs making a folder under the master repo

Tags: git, github

Our team is not familiar with Git and I feel like we are not using it correctly.

They have opened a github account with the lab's name. different people (not necessarily working on the same project) have a folder with their name and they use that to organize their code. If one needs someone else's code, he copies it to his own folder and uses it as he wants.

This is a small team of about 6 people (working on different stuff sometimes) so the codes are not changing very fast.

Is it the correct way of doing this?  Or should different people have their own account and fork the project and merge it later?

Is there any good tutorial out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your team members should have their own GitHub account, not one for the whole team. You may want to consider creating an Organization or turning the current account that owns the repository into an Organization at https://github.com/settings/organizations (free for open source). Add each team member as a collaborator.

From there, team members can work in branches, their own personal forks of the repository, or all together in the master branch of the main repository.

In any case, they should **not** be copying code back and forth in personal folders in the repository. That largely defeats the purpose of having version control in the first place. If I need to use your code and copy it to my folder, and then you make changes to your copy, I am now working with out-of-date code.

Answer (score 2):

A Github 'fork' is a Git clone of a Github repository that is hosted on Github; nothing more and nothing less.  A Github 'fork' is useful because Github restricts who can push to a repository.  You need to be a 'collaborator' to push; if you are not a collaborator then you fork so that you have a Github repository that you **can** push to.

In your case, it doesn't sound like you need a fork.  You just create a Github repository, add all your team members as collaborators, and have each team member clone the Github repository.  At that point the team is ready to develop.

As for tutorials, a search for 'git tutorial' or 'git workflow' will turn up lots of useful information.  'git help' is your friend too.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound as if the fork/pull request way of doing this might work better. Try having one account per person, and forks of each others' stuff.

There are many good tutorials. Here's a couple of examples:

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

http://git-scm.com/book